# ¿Cómo obtener la selección en EF Core y Linq de un objeto anidado?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable.

Tengo una serie de tablas enlazadas entre sí Tabla1-->Tabla2-->Tabla3-->Tabla4
La relación en ese sentido es de 1 a muchos (un registro de la tabla1 está enlazado con varios de la tabla2, cada uno de la tabla2 con varios de la tabla3...etc).

Me proporcionan un identificador de la Tabla1 y debo obtener el conjunto de datos de alguna propiedad de la tabla 4 (pero solo esos datos).
Encadenando un include y varios theninclude en LINQ puedo llegar hasta la última tabla, pero... ¿cómo puedo seleccionar solo esos datos?

Tengo algo así:

```
_databaseContext.Table1.Where(t1 => t1.Id == id)
                .Include(t1 => t1.Table2Nav)
                .ThenInclude(t2 => t2.Table3Nav)
                .ThenInclude(t3 => t3.Table4Nav)
                .ToList();
```

Esto me devuelve la estructura completa desde la primera tabla, pero ¿de qué forma puedo hacer un select de elementos concretos de la tabla 4 (supongamos que la tabla 4 tiene una propiedad llamada "Resultado" y necesito recuperar una lista de todos los valores de "Resultado" a los que se llega partiendo desde el Id de la tabla 1.

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que algo así podría solucionar tu problema

```
  var result = from T1 in _databaseContext.Table1
                  join T2 in _databaseContext.Table2 on ....
                  join T3 in _databaseContext.Table3 on ....
                  join T4 in _databaseContext.Table4 on ....
                 Where T1.Id == id
                 Select T4
```